# I used tradingview widget in my next app, it works with a glitch, if i navigate out/in, the chart disappears, but if i refresh the the chart appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, fetch

This is the code for the tradingview chart, the script loads the imported tradingview function on page load and i added a function to programmatically reload the dashboard onClick

```
import Script from "next/script"
import styles from "./Charts.module.css"
import { renderChart } from "../utils/text"
import BarLoader from "react-spinners/BarLoader";
import { useRouter } from "next/router"

export default function Charts() {

  const router = useRouter()

return (
<div className={styles.container}>
 <div className={`tradingview-widget-container ${styles.tv}`}>
    <div id="tradingview_70c8b">
      <Script  src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js" onLoad={renderChart}/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.reload} onClick={() => router.reload()}>
    <BarLoader color="#00e99b" loading={true}/>
    <h6>No data available for display...</h6>
    <p>Tap to refresh</p>
  </div>
</div>
)}
```

This's the tradingview function i imported from my utils just to keep the code neat

```
export const renderChart = () => {
  new TradingView.MediumWidget(
  {
  "symbols": [
    [
      "Gold",
      "TVC:GOLD|1D"
    ],
    [
      "Bitcoin",
      "BITSTAMP:BTCUSD|1D"
    ],
    [
      "Tether",
      "CRYPTOCAP:USDT|1D"
    ],
    [
      "Diamond",
      "BSE:DIAMOND|1D"
    ],
    [
      "Oil",
      "SPARKS:OIL|1D"
    ],
    [
      "USOIL",
      "TVC:USOIL|1D"
    ],
    [
      "Google",
      "CAPITALCOM:GOOG|12M"
    ],
    [
      "Apple",
      "NASDAQ:AAPL|12M"
    ],
    [
      "Microsoft",
      "NASDAQ:MSFT|12M"
    ]
  ],
  "chartOnly": false,
  "width": "100%",
  "height": "100%",
  "locale": "en",
  "colorTheme": "dark",
  "autosize": true,
  "showVolume": true,
  "hideDateRanges": false,
  "scalePosition": "right",
  "scaleMode": "Normal",
  "fontFamily": "trinidad_neue_blackregular",
  "noTimeScale": true,
  "valuesTracking": "5",
  "chartType": "line",
  "fontColor": "rgba(120, 123, 134, 0.57)",
  "gridLineColor": "rgba(240, 243, 250, 0.03)",
  "volumeUpColor": "rgba(34, 171, 148, 0.5)",
  "volumeDownColor": "rgba(247, 82, 95, 0.5)",
  "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
  "container_id": "tradingview_70c8b"
})
}
```

i get this errors on my console every time the component mounts

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/content_scroll_mid_detection.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_check.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://fheoggkfdfchfphceeifdbepaooicaho/sourceMap/chrome/scripts/iframe_form_detection.map: System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
6373.32ed9c17ad0037ce6878.js:5 2022-08-30T17:47:00.594Z:Chart.MiniChart:Container position property must be: relative, fixed, absolute
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dynamic import of chart

https://tradingview-widgets.jorrinkievit.xyz/docs/Usage%20with%20Next.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you
i suspected that